# Can install a test machine with Oracle 11G R2, not express edition, on a VirtualBox?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2

Im starting like a Oracle DBA, and I want play with the database and your administration task in a test enviroment.

I have a macbook pro i5, and had thought install on it oracle under virtual box machine.

- What distro of linux your recommends me to start?
- I can install Oracle RAC in a Vbox machine?
- Some handbook?
- Other considerations...

I appreciate all your comments, and excuse my poor english D:

Comment: You can easily find some developer editions for oracle virtualbox: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=oracle+virtualbox+developer+download I've tried them out myself, and they're quite easy to set up / get the basics on. You might want to try that before asking for further help.

Comment: You can certainly use the developer distros available on technet.oracle.com. You need to create an account first, there should be no cost to do that. Then while you are logged in goto, https://edelivery.oracle.com/EPD/Search/handle_go and you should be able to download a prebuilt VM. You can also try downloading Centos. Centos is a Redhat clone that should give you everything that you would get if you install Redhat.

Comment: Just my opinion based on experience, but for the OS distro, I'd recommend Oracle Enterprise Linux. It's based off of Fedora. Pretty mainstream, most places are going to use a Red Hat or its derivative distro. You could go with AIX, Solaris, or even Windows, but those are much more distinctive to specific hardware and IMO they are not nearly as prevalent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer some of your questions, firstly read this: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/indexes/downloads/index.html and this http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/licenses/standard-license-152015.html.  These are your licencing restrictions.

All the manuals are available here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/index.htm. Read the installation guide, specifically.  If you want to install Oracle DB yourself, there's lots you can do without reading it, but you'll achieve more if you do.

As to distributions, that's totally up to you.  Obviously Oracle Linux is a good place to start, but have a look at the supported platforms lists.  Personally I like RHEL/CentOS/OL, but that's just what I've most experience with.

You can install RAC in VMs, not a problem.  Have a look at this as an example: https://martincarstenbach.files.wordpress.com/2012/03/rac-attack-using-virtualbox.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Most of your questions are covered in official documentation.
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/nav/portal_11.htm

Read the installation guide (NOT the "quick installation" one).

I don't recommend using "pre-built" virtual machines - try to install OS and db from scratch. The process is the same as installing on "real" hardware. Use CentOS as mentioned in comments.

Not sure for RAC, but Data Guard works perfectly.

Good luck and have fun :)